# Is it possible to deploy chaincode in Hyperledger Composer Set Up?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Am working on Hyperledger composer.I have developed the Chaincode in Go language. Is it possible to deploy the Chaincode written in Go language on a Hyperledger Composer Environment? Am using the latest composer version:0.19.12. please guide..

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is possible. Hyperledger Composer interacts with the Javascript runtime and does not communicate in any way with the GO runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer business networks are capable of invoking chaincode from TP functions in the business network. So you can get a business network to interact with your GO Chaincode. You would use the `getNativeAPI` method inside a business network to get access to the stub and then can then perform an `invokeChaincode` request on that stub.

Hyperledger Composer doesn't provide a Fabric network, it requires a fabric network to be deployed to (a business network is, at the end of the day, chaincode).